# Windows boot black screen

Tags: windows-8.1

I have an Acer laptop,  Windows 8.1. This evening I turned it on.  It went to lo gin screen as usual,  I entered my password,  it accepted it.  However it didn't bring me to my desktop it just showed the color of the login screen.  Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First try restarting your computer. If the screen is still open, you can try briefly pressing the power button. This should initiate a regular shutdown (same as selecting shutdown from the Start Menu). If it doesn't respond after a couple minutes, hold down the power button until the computer turns off and turn it back on. If the problem continues after restarting, try entering Safe Mode and performing a System Restore.

You can enter Safe Mode through the advanced startup options menu. You can reach this menu by holding the Shift key while selecting Restart on the power menu at the bottom right of the login screen.

If System Restore isn't working for you, you can try running **sfc /scannow** inside an Administrator command prompt in safe mode. You can run the command prompt as Administrator by right-clicking and selecting the option. This will scan your system files for corruption and attempt to restore them. If you receive a failure message, reboot into Safe Mode and try running it again. Try this up to 3 times.

If sfc is still having problems, you can try using DISM instead. There is a very thorough guide located here: http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/26512-dism-fixing-component-store-corruption-windows-8-a.html